# How to test Android Q gesture navigation on emulator?

Tags: android, android-10.0

Is there any way to test the new [gesture navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/gesturenav) on Android Emulator?

I created `x86 Pixel 3a XL Android 10.0 (without Google APIs)` emulator and it has the standard navigation bar and in `Settings > System > Gestures`, there is no option to enable the gesture-based navigation or hide the nav bar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Seems there were some issues with my SDK or the way I created the emulator. Uninstalling Android Q **Preview**, deleting the emulator, installing the latest Android 10 image and creating a new emulator helped.

Now I can enable gestural navigation in `Settings > System > Gestures > System Navigation`